# How to I train a model for a certain number of rows in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, modeling, training-data

I am creating a model and have 1876 rows. I would like to use 1000 of them for training and 876 of them for testing. I am unsure how to do this, currently, I have the following:

```
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)
```

This is by the percentage which is not the goal currently but it is all I know how to do. Does anyone have suggestions of how I could change this code to get exactly 1000 training and 876 testing rows? I understand that this is likely a sub-optimal split. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using `sklearn`? Did you read the documentation? You can simply enter an integer.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You're asking to find "1000 is what percentage of 1876?"  This is basic arithmetic.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: @blorgon I am using sklearn, I was unaware you could enter the integer.

Comment: @Prune I was trying to be cleaner than entering .53304904051 for my percentage of training. I am just learning so I am trying to find different ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df_train = df.iloc[:1000]
df_test = df.iloc[1000:]
```

Answer (score 0):

As  @blorgon wrote you can use integers instead of percentages but also Pandas has the sample function, which samples n items randomly (so you can choose n=1000)
here is the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Answer (score 0):

test_size=0.20 means 20% of 1876 will result in the test data. use test_size=.46

```
 1876*.46=1876-862=1014 (test size)
```